# Find the non duplicate element in an array where the duplicates are adjacent in less than o(n) time

Tags: algorithm

Array example: 8 8 1 1 4 6 6 2 2 9 9 =>result: 4
Is it even possible in less then O(n), like O(logn)? The person who gave this to me said it was possible. I need an answer in within 12 hrs.

Comment: The non duplicate could be the final element of the array, so there is no way this could be < O(n)

Comment: that's what i thought too, but the person keeps insisting that it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it's possible with O(lg n)
we know the size of array is 2n+1, and n is the middle of array

```
Search(A)
  if A[n] is not equal to it's adjacent, it's the answer
  else 
    find the equal adjacent to A[n]
    if(n is even)
       search within the half array that is equal to A[n]
    if n is odd
       search within the half array that is not equal to A[n]
```

in you example:

```
8 8 1 1 4 6 6 2 2 9 9,  n is 5
          n
```

A[n] is equal to it's right adjacent, n is odd so we search in the left half

```
8 8 1 1 4 , n is 2
    n
```

A[n] is equal to it's right adjacent , n is even, so we search in right half

and etc

Comment: So start with an array like `8 8 1 1 1 1 1 6 6 2 2 2 4 9 9`. The middle element is the first 6 at `n = 7` which is odd. Your algorithm says we should search the left half, but that's not where the single digit is. Also, what do you do if the number has numbers equal on both sides?

Comment: the algorithm works if duplicates has two repeats, as question example , and doesn't work in your case .